# Cassandra bind sql in statement

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver, nosql

Is there anyway to bind to an SQL IN statement using Cassandra and the datastax driver?

I will be passing a variable amount of parameters to the SQL in statement.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, would you mind providing more detail or show us a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I already figured it out.  What I was trying to do is simply execute an "SQL IN" statement.  And since I'm new to Cassandra and datastax, I wasn't aware of the setList method which is used to specify the parameters of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.  I needed to use the setList parameter in Boundstatement.